# thumbnails transition jumping

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-transitions

Please take a look at http://michalpodkowa.pl
When you hover over thumbnails in last column, images after transition are jumping a bit, especially in firefox. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: on a small note, this site is Awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Add following script at the end of your page.

```
<script>
    $("#gallery").css("width",parseInt($(window).width())+0.1);
</script>
```